# How to get tenths of second, hundredth of second, etc from an NSTimeInterval

Tags: swift, time, milliseconds, nstimeinterval, seconds

How do I get tenths of second, hundredth of second, millisecond, etc. from an `NSTimeInterval` in Swift?

Comment: just divide it by 10, 100, 1000

Comment: Of what?  An `NStimeInterval`?  `NSDate`?

Answer (score 2):

`NSTimeInterval` is a representation of seconds as a `typealias` of `Double`.  You can get the tenths, hundreths, etc. of a second by diving its value:

```
let timeInterval = NSTimeInterval(1.0) // 1 second

let tenth = timeInterval / 10.0 // 0.1
let hundreth = timeInterval / 100.0 // 0.01
let millisecond = timeInterval / 1000.0 // 0.001
```